# Combine data from two seperate tables in Power Pivot without using a join based on concatenated key

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot, dax

I have two separate data sources with effectively the same columns

- Date
- Vendor
- Campaign
- Ad group
- Keyword
- Impressions
- Spend

What I am trying to do is stitch the data together in a fact table in order to get a combined view of Impressions and Spend. However, as I am dealing with 2.5 million rows, as soon as I make a concatenated key to join the data `=[Date]&[Vendor]&[Campaign]&[Ad Group]&[Keyword]`, my file size jumps from 11Mb to 100Mb, I assume due to the high level of the cardinality in my new column.

What I am wondering is, how can I get join this data together that would remove the need for this concatenated key? I have a date table in place if that helps, but would a method that would utilize a measure instead of a calculated column would be ideal.

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a Power Query layer using the Append command to combine the 2 fact tables into one.  The combined table would be what is presented in Power Pivot.

Impressions rows will have blank Spend values, and vice versa.  Your chosen aggregation for the 2 measures should take care of that.

Comment: Simplicity is the best. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much for the insight!